# How do you generate multivariate Gaussian random numbers in R?

Tags: r, random, gaussian

How do we generate data points following a Gaussian (normal) distribution in R?

Suppose I want to generate points in 2d (or higher dimensional) space that follow a Gaussian distribution. How do I do this using R?

Comment: `?distributions` is a good starting point

Comment: Almost identical post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2079772/602276

Comment: I like the `mvtnorm` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One dimensional: `?rnorm`. More dimensions: install and load package mvtnorm and use `rmvnorm()`.

Comment: Beat me to it! Curse your fast typing! :)

Answer (score 8):

Gaussian distributions are for one dimensional random variables.  You can generate them using [`rnorm`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/rnorm).

```
rnorm(100, mean = 3, sd = 2)
```

For the higher dimensional case you want a multivariate normal distribution instead.  Try [`mvrnorm`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/MASS/docs/mvrnorm) in the `MASS` package, or [`rmvnorm`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/mvtnorm/docs/rmvnorm) in the `mvtnorm` package.

```
library(mvtnorm)
rmvnorm(100, mean = c(3, 5), sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 2), nrow = 2))
```

Further reading: [`?Distributions`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/Distributions) and the [CRAN Task View on distributions](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html).